# How can I rotate the quadrants of a circle by a certain angle and define Qs of other angles?

Tags: java, python, math, trigonometry

I couldn't really find any mention of this problem, so I hope this is fine.

I am trying to determine which quadrants a set of angles belongs to, with the caveat that the quadrants are always rotated by a varying angle on a case-by-case basis.

If the quadrants were defined as per those of the unit circle, then the solution would be relatively easy as the angle intervals are well-set.

However, how can this be performed when the quadrants are rotated? Redefining the quadrants numerically seems to lead to all sorts of specific problem cases (e.g. every single one of the quadrants now has to have a function that resets it to define intervals that include the shift back to 0 degrees), and I think I'm missing something that would make this far simpler.

To solve this problem, ideally I would only have to use the quadrant rotation angle and the angles that I know are defined within the circle, but I could also use point coordinates if need be (I think atan2 would help in solving the latter, but again, I would like to avoid it).

[Image for visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBD3X.png)

A: Unit circle

B/C: Unit circle rotated with the orange angle defining the mid-point of Q1, with the blue angles being what I want to determine the distribution of, i.e. B: 1 in Q1, 1 in Q4; C: 1 in Q3, 1 in Q4.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take an offset value to calculate the quadrants.

```
Q1 = 0° - 89°
Q2 = 90° - 179°
Q3 = ...
```

To calculate in which quadrant the line is you just do floor division.
`quadrant = (angle + offset) // 90`

Returns 0 for Q1, 1 for Q2, etc.
Offset is the rotation of the circle clockwise.